# Is it possible for me to style every 1st 5th 9th 13th 16th with this gap of 3 items in list in normal list or div list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hav a row in which i have to manage 3 column in single row then a single column in a sigle row after that then again row of 3 column with margin-left css but i want to disable this css for 1st 5th 9th 13th 16th list 
is it possible with any css

```
<ul>
 <li>A</li>
 <li>B</li>
 <li>C</li>
 <li>D</li>
 <li>E</li>
 <li>F</li>
 <li>G</li>
 <li>H</li>
 <li>I</li>
 <li>J</li>
</ul>
```

A B C will be in row
single D will be in next row
E F G will be in next row
single H will be in next row
I J K will be in next row
...

so in this case i want to apply css to only A, E, I , n so on....please guide

Comment: Unable to understand the question. Please eleaborate and what expected outcome you want. add that too

Comment: @AlivetoDie is right, your question is a bit hard to understand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try look into :nth-child(n) CSS selector. In your case you might want to use:

```
ul li:nth-child(4n+1) {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is simple maths. The rule is simple to deduct. All 4th letter is different from the other... And need another class.

1. Loop through each list items (`li`) and compare the loop `index` to a
   "counter".
2. Initially set that counter to 3, since the 4th letter has to match with a zero-based index.
3. On "match", add 4 again.

And that's it.

```js
var counter = 3;

$("ul li").each(function(index){

  if( index == counter ){
    $(this).addClass("red");
    counter+=4;
  }

});
```

```css
li{
  display:inline-block;
}
li.red {
  color: red;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li>H</li>
  <li>I</li>
  <li>J</li>
  <li>K</li>
  <li>L</li>
  <li>M</li>
  <li>N</li>
  <li>O</li>
  <li>P</li>
  <li>Q</li>
  <li>R</li>
  <li>S</li>
  <li>T</li>
  <li>U</li>
  <li>V</li>
  <li>W</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Z</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS only** does it fine too.

```css
li{
  display:inline-block;
}
li:nth-child(4n) {
  color: red;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li>H</li>
  <li>I</li>
  <li>J</li>
  <li>K</li>
  <li>L</li>
  <li>M</li>
  <li>N</li>
  <li>O</li>
  <li>P</li>
  <li>Q</li>
  <li>R</li>
  <li>S</li>
  <li>T</li>
  <li>U</li>
  <li>V</li>
  <li>W</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Z</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector.

```
li:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
  color: red;
}
```

Result you can check [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VyxgbQ).